# How to Bind a component on click of element in multiselect of angular formly Reactive forms

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-formly

I have a reuquirement in which i am using a multiselect dropdwon which also has logo for each row. On click of this logo i want to load other component, like we use viewchild in template driven approach is it possible to use it in Reactive formly form component?

**Step 1:** Open multiselect of formly element.
**Step 2:** There is a logo in each row, on click of logo  a method is called and need to load calender component in popup.
**Step 3 :** Load contents of calendar-component.html in modal popup.

Stackblitz workaround of example for demonstration : [Click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-ui-primeng-zlekna?file=app/app.component.ts)

Screenshot for logo in multiselect:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can create a function to verify if it model is selected:

```
 isSelected() {
   return this.model.hasOwnProperty('select') && this.model['select'].length;
  }
```

and at your template you can call your calendar on that condition:

```
Entered Values
<div> {{model|json}}</div>
<calender *ngIf="isSelected()"></calender>
```

**formly approach**

as [formly](https://formly.dev/guide/properties-options) states you can also provide at your template as output `modelChange` to trigger actions on model updates. this way your formy tag would look like:

```
  <formly-form [model]="model" [fields]="fields"
    (modelChange)="displayCalender()"
  >
```

and you define `displayCalender` funcionality at your component:

```
 displayCalender() {
   // logic to render your calender 
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-ui-primeng-jxpyap?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: I am not sure whether it will work with formly, I have modified the example accordingly, please help me out in this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-ui-primeng-c9t5w3?file=app/formly-field-primeng-multiselect.ts

Comment: I updated to check if select array is empty

Comment: can you please help me out, to provide a workaround in the stackbltiz example I mentioned above.

Comment: here is the updated code https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-ui-primeng-gbfku2?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I have modified the code accordingly, my requirement is when i click the logo  of formly element, calling function displayCalender() through which calenderComponent should load in bootstrap modal can you please help me out in this Link for modified code:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-ui-primeng-cjukhx?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly, where it provides a clean approach for you to call your requested function. I think that allows you to advance with your project. if you feel like that answer your inquiry than I would appreciate you consider to accept it as the answer for your question. best regards :)